# Active Record: How to read from db objects that has many other objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Imagine I have a model of Ticket that has many Attachments. In ticket model I have:

```
has_many :attachment, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'Ticket::Attachment'
```

And now I need to read from db tickets that have one or more attachments (ticket can also have no attachments at all).
I found that I can "go" through all tickets and check if `attachment.empty?` but it is not efficient, because at the beginning I read all tickets from db. I'd like to read from db only those records that have > 0 attachments in this active record query. How to do that?

Comment: In general I wanted to use `where`, something like this: `Ticket.where(attachment: nil)`.

Comment: Perhaps `Ticket.where(attachment: nil)` should be `Ticket.where.not(attachment: nil)`.

Comment: This is what I need, but this query does not work

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question carefully, only the original comment. `has_many` is conventionally followed by the plural form: `has_many :attachments, ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should only give you Tickets where there are attachements:

`Ticket.joins(:attachments).group("tickets.id")`

It will perform an inner join between the 2 tables only returning rows that exist in both tables and then group them by `Ticket.id` so you get rows of unique tickets.